# Rename tags when copy azure container registry

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I have to edit/rename the tag when copy Azure Container Registry. I have tried different options but from the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/repository?view=azure-cli-latest) doesn't look like it is been supported. Does anyone know about another approach?

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate across your existing old registry to list each image and for each image issue

```
az acr import --name  newregistryname --source  somesourceregistry/sourceoriginalimagename:oldtag --image mynewimagename:somenewtag
```

which will define one image in your `newregistryname` which will have image name of `mynewimagename:somenewtag`

Comment: Anything from AZ Powershell module? I am using `Import-AzContainerRegistryImage`.